# Should I use ANOVA or Kruskal Wallis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, kruskal-wallis-test

I have 10 samples and 2 treatments. One of the treatments only has 1 samples in it and the distribution is not normal at all. This is my main concern because it violates the assumption that the dependent variable is normally distributed in ***each*** group that is being compared in the one-way ANOVA. Overall the distribution of 10 samples is a bit skewed, but it's not too alarming.

Since my sample size isn't too small, I thought that CLT will come into play and that will allow me to use ANOVA (data also meets equal variance and independence assumption). However since one of the treatments only has 1 samples in it (and is not normally distributed) I'm a bit worried because I'm not sure how much effect that will have on my results. Should I turn to Kruskal-Wallis instead?

Comment: How can you check, with only five points, relevant non-normality of the underlying true population? As long as the variances are not too different (at least in the four big groups), there is no reason to worry. You need to be careful though with pairwise comparisons that involve this small group.

Comment: Well I read that "The dependent variable is normally distributed in each group that is being compared in the one-way ANOVA. " is an assumption for ANOVA from https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/one-way-anova-statistical-guide-2.php. And the distribution of those 5 points is clearly non-normal. So I'm wondering if it's still ok to use ANOVA under these circumstances.

Comment: Since you're particularly concerned about the 5 points, why not tell us what the values are? You show a Q-Q plot that you (correctly) regard as not problematic, which doesn't help us judge what your actual problem is. What are the other two sample sizes (they add to 53, but are they close to even or not)?

Comment: @Glen_b I have edited my original post. Please have a look.

Comment: Why makes you say that sample of 5 is a problem? I've just simulated a bunch of samples of size 5 from a $N(50,10^2)$ and the QQ plot for your small sample there would fit in with them just fine; you regularly see weirder looking plots. (Actually, looking at the y-axis of your original Q-Q plot, that's showing the marginal distribution of the response about which no assumption is made; you can't really conclude anything from that; to combine the samples, look at residuals)